# reset the content of temporary files whenever code s done running

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

currently I'm working on this code :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo enter any characters:
read input
$input > file.tmp   
sort file.tmp
echo number of characters entered : 
wc -l file.tmp
exit
```

basically i want to the user to enter any characters and count the number of characters that the user have entered.I store the input to a temporary files so that after the code is done running, the content of the files is cleared.But , whenever i run the code again, the content of the file.tmp is not cleared, so the previous list of character is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s' 'enter any characters: '
IFS= read -r input
echo "number of characters entered : ${#input}"
```

In operation, this looks like:

```
$ sh script.sh
enter any characters: This is a test.
number of characters entered : 15
```

#### Discussion

Two changes were made to the `read` statement:

1. The `-r` option was added to so that backslashes, `\`, are treated as normal characters.
2. By default, `read` will strip off leading and trailing whitespace from the input.  To keep those spaces so that they are counted toward characters entered, `IFS` was set to empty.  (If you do *not* want to count such spaces, replace `IFS= read -r input` with `read -r input`.)

Referring to the script in the question:

- `$input > file.tmp`

  This does not write the contents of `input` to `file.tmp`.  It tells the shell to try to interpret the contents of `input` as a command and execute it.
- `sort file.tmp`

  This prints the sorted contents of `file.tmp`.  It does not alter `file.tmp` in any way.
- `wc -l file.tmp`

  The `-l` option tells `wc` to count the number of *lines*.  This conflicts with the `echo` statement that claimed to be reporting the number of characters.
- `exit`

  Shell scripts always exit when they get to the end.  There is no need for an explicit exit command unless you intend to set a return code for the script.
- Nothing in the code would cause `file.tmp` to be deleted.  To delete it, you would need to run `rm file.tmp`.  This might be best done as part of a `trap` statement if you want to be sure that the deletion happens.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Excellent suggestions!  I updated the answer to include both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#! /bin/bash

IFS= read -rep "Enter characters: " s
echo "${#s} characters entered."
```

Some explanations : the `-r` option of `read` is to get raw input without interpreting the backslashes ; `-p` echoes the question; and `-e` uses `readline` to read the input.

To prevent `read` to skip the spaces at the beginning and end of the input, `IFS` is emptied.

`${#s}` expands to the lenght of `s`.